# How to move word with ansible regex_replace

Tags: regex, replace, ansible

How can I move words with ansible `regex_replace`.

I have `foo_jenkins` and would like to obtain `secret/foo`

hashicorp_vault_role_name : foo_jenkins

```
- name: "Create policy Jenkins"
  hashivault_policy_set:
    name: "{{hashicorp_vault_role_name}}"
    rules: >
      path "{{ hashicorp_vault_role_name|regex_replace('?', '?') }}/*" {
        capabilities = ["list"]
      }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What did your try on your side? Can you show us where you are with your playbook/task?

Comment: Please take some time to get accustomed with the site rules in the help section. You are not supposed to add this info into comments but to edit your question (and make sure you format the code correctly). You will get a much better experience here if you take some time to understand all this before firing questions and comments.

Comment: ok nice ,see my code in the post ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you gave, the following should get you going:

```
{{ hashicorp_vault_role_name | regex_replace('(.*)_jenkins', 'secret/\\1') }}
```

Basically, take the value of `hashicorp_vault_role_name`, match anything followed by `_jenkins` capturing the first part of the expression and replace with `secret/` followed by the previous capture.

If your need to change the logic a bit or you have other operations of the same type to perform, I suggest you take some time [learning regular expressions](https://regexr.com/).